# prefersStatusBarHidden not working with presentation "Over Full Screen"

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have Viewcontroller "Home" that have Menu button on navigationBar, when user click on meny i display ViewController over home to display Menu.

To do this i set "Defines context" to the home ViewController

[image]

and Presentation to "Over Full Screen" to the menu ViewController

[image]

Menu containt buttons that have segues to new storyboard that contains UINavigation and ViewControllers

[image]

On that ViewControllers i have this function

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
     return true
}
```

This function is called but StatusBars is not hidden

I have "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to YES

The problem come from "Over Full Screen" because when i change it, it work but for my design i need to use "Over Full Screen"